# Dependency error while upgrading to rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade, ruby-on-rails-5.2, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to upgrade to rails 6 from rails 5.2, following these instructions:

https://blog.rubynetti.it/i/how-to-upgrade-to-rails-6-from-rails-5-2-1

When I run `bundle update`, I get the following errors and don't know how to fix them. I tried, deleting my lock file, and running it again, I tried running `bundle update railties`, but get an error saying I should run 'bundle update'

Please help!

#### Error message after `bundle update`

```
Resolving dependencies........
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    coffee-rails (~> 4.2) was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.0.0)

    devise was resolved to 4.7.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.1.0)

    factory_bot_rails was resolved to 5.1.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.2.0)

    jquery-ui-rails was resolved to 6.0.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.2.16)

    rails (~> 6.0, >= 6.0.2.1) was resolved to 6.0.2.1, which depends on
      railties (= 6.0.2.1)

    rspec-rails (~> 3.8) was resolved to 3.9.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.0)

    teaspoon-jasmine was resolved to 2.3.4, which depends on
      teaspoon (>= 1.0.0) was resolved to 1.1.4, which depends on
        railties (>= 3.2.5, < 5)

    web-console (>= 3.3.0) was resolved to 4.0.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 6.0.0)

    wicked was resolved to 1.3.4, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.0.7)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "thor":
  In Gemfile:
    jquery-rails was resolved to 4.3.5, which depends on
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)

    rails (~> 6.0, >= 6.0.2.1) was resolved to 6.0.2.1, which depends on
      railties (= 6.0.2.1) was resolved to 6.0.2.1, which depends on
        thor (>= 0.20.3, < 2.0)

    select2-rails was resolved to 4.0.3, which depends on
      thor (~> 0.14)
```

#### gemfile

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.2.1'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.4'
gem 'active_hash'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
gem 'puma', '~> 3.12'
gem 'sassc'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.3.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise-bootstrap-views', '~> 1.0'
gem 'devise-i18n'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 5.0.1'
gem "select2-rails"
gem 'wicked'
gem 'pagy'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'mailboxer'
gem 'stripe'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'activerecord-import'
gem 'rubocop', require: false
gem 'rubocop-rails'
gem 'rubocop-performance'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~>3.8'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'faker', git: 'https://github.com/stympy/faker.git', branch: 'master'
  gem "teaspoon-jasmine"
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5'
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers', '~> 4.0'  
  gem 'stripe-ruby-mock', '~> 2.5.8', :require => 'stripe_mock'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby]
```

gemfile.lock

```
GIT
  remote: https://github.com/stympy/faker.git
  revision: 585093235822362e345034da46945b6ea8ssed9d
  branch: master
  specs:
    faker (2.9.0)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 1.8)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.2.4.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.4.1)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.2.4.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.4.1)
      actionview (= 5.2.4.1)
      activejob (= 5.2.4.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.2.4.1)
      actionview (= 5.2.4.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4.1)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.8)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.2.4.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    active_hash (3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    activejob (5.2.4.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.2.4.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4.1)
    activerecord (5.2.4.1)
      activemodel (= 5.2.4.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4.1)
      arel (>= 9.0)
    activerecord-import (1.0.4)
      activerecord (>= 3.2)
    activestorage (5.2.4.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.4.1)
      activerecord (= 5.2.4.1)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (5.2.4.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.7.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    arel (9.0.0)
    ast (2.4.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (9.7.3)
      execjs
    bcrypt (3.1.13)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.4.5)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    bootstrap (4.3.1)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 9.1.0)
      popper_js (>= 1.14.3, < 2)
      sassc-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.0.1)
    capybara (3.30.0)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (~> 1.5)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    carrierwave (2.0.2)
      activemodel (>= 5.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
      addressable (~> 2.6)
      image_processing (~> 1.1)
      mimemagic (>= 0.3.0)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
    childprocess (3.0.0)
    coderay (1.1.2)
    coffee-rails (4.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.5)
    crass (1.0.5)
    dante (0.2.0)
    database_cleaner (1.7.0)
    devise (4.7.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    devise-bootstrap-views (1.1.0)
    devise-i18n (1.9.0)
      devise (>= 4.7.1)
    diff-lcs (1.3)
    erubi (1.9.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    factory_bot (5.1.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    factory_bot_rails (5.1.1)
      factory_bot (~> 5.1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
    ffi (1.11.3)
    geocoder (1.5.2)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (1.7.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    image_processing (1.10.0)
      mini_magick (>= 4.9.5, < 5)
      ruby-vips (>= 2.0.13, < 3)
    jaro_winkler (1.5.4)
    jbuilder (2.9.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    jquery-rails (4.3.5)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (6.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    listen (3.2.1)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    loofah (2.4.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    mailboxer (0.15.1)
      carrierwave (>= 0.5.8)
      rails (>= 5.0.0)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (0.9.2)
    mimemagic (0.3.3)
    mini_magick (4.9.5)
    mini_mime (1.0.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    minitest (5.13.0)
    msgpack (1.3.1)
    multi_json (1.14.1)
    nio4r (2.5.2)
    nokogiri (1.10.7)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pagy (3.7.1)
    parallel (1.19.1)
    parser (2.7.0.0)
      ast (~> 2.4.0)
    pg (0.18.4)
    popper_js (1.14.5)
    pry (0.12.2)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.9.0)
    public_suffix (4.0.2)
    puma (3.12.2)
    rack (2.0.8)
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.2.4.1)
      actioncable (= 5.2.4.1)
      actionmailer (= 5.2.4.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.4.1)
      actionview (= 5.2.4.1)
      activejob (= 5.2.4.1)
      activemodel (= 5.2.4.1)
      activerecord (= 5.2.4.1)
      activestorage (= 5.2.4.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.2.4.1)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (5.2.4.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.4.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.4.1)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.19.0, < 2.0)
    rainbow (3.0.0)
    rake (13.0.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    regexp_parser (1.6.0)
    responders (3.0.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    rspec-core (3.9.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.9.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.9.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.9.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.9.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.9.0)
    rspec-rails (3.9.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.9.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.9.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.9.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.9.0)
    rspec-support (3.9.0)
    rubocop (0.78.0)
      jaro_winkler (~> 1.5.1)
      parallel (~> 1.10)
      parser (>= 2.6)
      rainbow (>= 2.2.2, < 4.0)
      ruby-progressbar (~> 1.7)
      unicode-display_width (>= 1.4.0, < 1.7)
    rubocop-performance (1.5.2)
      rubocop (>= 0.71.0)
    rubocop-rails (2.4.1)
      rack (>= 1.1)
      rubocop (>= 0.72.0)
    ruby-progressbar (1.10.1)
    ruby-vips (2.0.16)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    rubyzip (2.0.0)
    sassc (2.2.1)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    select2-rails (4.0.3)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    selenium-webdriver (3.142.7)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
    simple_form (5.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
    spring (2.1.0)
    spring-commands-rspec (1.0.4)
      spring (>= 0.9.1)
    sprockets (4.0.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    stripe (5.11.0)
    stripe-ruby-mock (2.5.8)
      dante (>= 0.2.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      stripe (>= 2.0.3)
    teaspoon (1.1.5)
      railties (>= 3.2.5, < 6)
    teaspoon-jasmine (2.3.4)
      teaspoon (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.20.3)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.6)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.2.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    unicode-display_width (1.6.0)
    warden (1.2.8)
      rack (>= 2.0.6)
    web-console (3.7.0)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    webdrivers (4.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 3.0, < 4.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.1)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.4)
    wicked (1.3.4)
      railties (>= 3.0.7)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  active_hash
  activerecord-import
  bootsnap (>= 1.1.0)
  bootstrap (~> 4.3.1)
  byebug
  capybara (>= 2.15)
  coffee-rails (~> 4.2)
  database_cleaner
  devise
  devise-bootstrap-views (~> 1.0)
  devise-i18n
  factory_bot_rails
  faker!
  geocoder
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  jquery-rails
  jquery-ui-rails
  listen (>= 3.0.5)
  mailboxer
  pagy
  pg (~> 0.18.4)
  pry
  puma (~> 3.12)
  rails (~> 5.2.3)
  rspec-rails (~> 3.8)
  rubocop
  rubocop-performance
  rubocop-rails
  sassc
  select2-rails
  selenium-webdriver
  simple_form (~> 5.0.1)
  spring-commands-rspec
  stripe
  stripe-ruby-mock (~> 2.5.8)
  teaspoon-jasmine
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)
  webdrivers (~> 4.0)
  wicked

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.6.5p114

BUNDLED WITH
   2.0.2
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar issue when upgrading. There's a lot of noise in these dependency warnings, so it can be tricky to find the issue, so it's all about knowing where to look. Luckily one of the devs I work with was able to help me out.

**railties**

The issue here is that `railties`, because it is a gem that ships with rails, is trying to upgrade to version 6, but your `teaspoon-jasmine` gem has a  sub-dependency (`teaspoon`) that requires `railties` `>= 3.2.5, < 5`. In most situations like this you would want upgrade `teaspoon-jasmine` to a version that supports rails 6, but it looks like you have the latest version of `teaspoon-jasmine` (2.3.4), so I would look into maybe getting rid of this if you can and replace it with a gem that is still being maintained, or if you need to you could fork that gem and configure it to work with rails 6.

**thor**

Very similar issue here that most likely has to do with `select2-rails`. This gem appears to not have been updated since 2016, and it requires an old version of `thor`. See gemspec for that gem [here](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails/blob/master/select2-rails.gemspec). I would do the same thing here and look into maybe getting rid of `select2-rails` if you can and replace it with a gem that is still being maintained, or if you need to you could fork that gem and configure it to work with rails 6.